# How to find the closest coordinate from a list of points?

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

Suppose I have a list of x, y coordinates as below:

```
A = [(26, 63), (23, 63), (22, 63), (21, 63), (20, 63), (22, 62), (27, 63)]
```

and I have a x, y coordinate of a point as below:

```
leftbottom = (0, 238)
```

Now, I want to find the closest point to the `leftbottom` point among the list `A`.

How can I do that most efficiently?

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from looping through the list A and calculate distance from leftbottom of every tuple? You can do that with the following formula: √[(x₂ - x₁)² + (y₂ - y₁)²]

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: leftbottom is not the coordinate, it is the value of the image in at (0, 238)

Comment: @Nastor: this would work but is slow. using numpy is better and has built in functions to do that

Comment: @Ben2209 If performance was a problem, OP would've said so. I just provided a native approach without external modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has a useful function : norm.

```
import numpy as np
A = [(26, 63), (25, 63), (24, 63), (23, 63), (22, 63), (21, 63), (20, 63), (22, 62), (27, 63)]
A = np.array(A)
leftbottom = np.array((0,238))
distances = np.linalg.norm(A-leftbottom, axis=1)
min_index = np.argmin(distances)
print(f"the closest point is {A[min_index]}, at a distance of {distances[min_index]}")
```

Result:

```
the closest point is [20 63], at a distance of 176.13914953808538
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a built-in solution, using the [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function over the list of points with the `key` argument being the distance of each point to the `target` point, calculated with [`math.hypot`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.hypot):

```py
import math

points = [(26, 80), (23, 24), (22, 63), (2, 63)] 
target = (1, 63)

print(min(points, key=lambda point: math.hypot(target[1]-point[1], target[0]-point[0])))
```

In this example, `(2, 63)` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

A = [(26, 63), (25, 63), (24, 63), (23, 63), (22, 63), (21, 63), (20, 63), (22, 62), (27, 63)]
p = (0, 238)

xy = np.array(A).T

# euclidean distance
d = ( (xy[0] - p[0]) ** 2 + (xy[1] - p[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5

closest_idx = np.argmin(d)
closest = A[closest_idx]

print(closest)
```

> (20, 63)

Comment: What is T and why it is not declared?

Comment: .T is a property of the array. It's the array transposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the closest coordinate simply in python.

Assume that leftbottom has same format with A.

**leftbottom = [(x,y)]**

```
import numpy as np
diffs = np.abs(np.array(A)-np.array(leftbottom))
dists = np.sum(dists,axis=1) #l1-distance
closest_point_index = np.argmin(dists)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution without using numpy maybe this can help you

```py
  from math import sqrt
  def min_distance(x, y, iterable):
       list_of_distances = list(map(lambda t: sqrt(pow(t[0]-x,2)+pow(t[1]-y,2)),iterable))
       min_res = min(list_of_distances)
       index_of_min = list_of_distances.index(min_res)
       return iterable[index_of_min]
   
   A = [(26, 63), (25, 63), (24, 63), (23, 63), (22, 63),(21, 63), (20, 63), (22, 62), (27, 63)]
   
   
  a = min_distance(0, 238, A)
  print(a)
```