# Coordinate pairing based on the smallest distance between two txt files

Tags: python

The goal would be to pair the measured coordinates with the smallest distance relative to a fixed coordinate set.

This is the base format of the txt. I tried to decompose the txt file into 3 lists as separate X Y Z coordinates and so on. The distance is ample in 2D.

[image]

And my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

nyers = pd.read_table('pontok.txt',header = None,index_col = False,delimiter= ',')
meres = pd.read_table('pontok_m.txt',header = None,index_col = False,delimiter= ',')

nyers_y = nyers[2]
nyers_x = nyers[2]
nyers_m = nyers[3]

meres_y = meres[1]
meres_x = meres[2]
meres_m = meres[3]

def distance(nyers, meres):

    d = math.sqrt((meres_y-nyers_y)**2 + (meres_x-nyers_x)**2)
    
shortest_distances = []
closest_points = []

for c1 in nyers:
    distances = [distance(c1, c2) for c2 in meres]
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    closest_points.append(meres[index])
    shortest_distances.append(distances[index])

result = np.hstack((nyers, closest_points, np.reshape(shortest_distances, (3, 1))))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the closest coordinate from a list of points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238749/how-to-find-the-closest-coordinate-from-a-list-of-points)

Comment: Unfortunately not.
For each point, I would need the point closest to it from the bare stock. For example, I have 5 planned points that I measure, but not in the correct order and the goal would be to pair the points so that I would assign the measured points to the planned points based on the distance.

Comment: Can't you just iterate over one of the answers that @Tomerikoo sugested you?